# Why DisplayMemeberPath doesn't accept a standard property?

Tags: wpf, binding, itemsource

I am binding a List of object to a ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox Name="comboPerson"  DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Where code behind looks like this:

```
List<Person> myFriends = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person("Jack", "Daniels", 8),
    new Person("Milla", "Jovovovich", 35),
    new Person("Umma", "Turman", 34)
};

comboPerson.ItemsSource = myFriends;
```

And if I use standart Properties, it doesn't display the name but, if the property is accessed via get accessors it is working. Here is what I mean:

Working version:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Surnamge { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }

public Person(string name, string surname, int age)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Surnamge = surname;
    this.Age = age;
}
```

Non working version:

```
public string Name;
public string Surnamge;
public int Age;

public Person(string name, string surname, int age)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Surnamge = surname;
    this.Age = age;
}
```

The question is: why WPF is unable to get the value from a standard Property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your "non working" version doesn't use Properties, it uses public Fields, which you usually should not use because it violates [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

WPF is designed so that it only accesses properties via their accessors. Fields are not accessed via accessors (which are generated by the compiler if you use the `{get;set;}` syntax), but directly.  If you use properties, you can also take advantage of nice things like automatic updating (if you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly).

So, if you want to use Binding in WPF, you'll need to use properties.

Comment: But what shall I do if the class library uses Fields instead of properties? How do I bind to those then?

Comment: You can't bind to fields. You could write a wrapper class that takes an instance of the library class and exposes its fields as properties.

Comment: And to get notification mechanism in my wrapper class do I have to check for changes in the library every n seconds and then rise PropertyCnaged event?

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility, if you expect the value to change over time.

Answer (score 1):

The second code doesn't contain standard properties, it contains fields. WPF needs properties, also you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, otherwise wpf won't catch changed data.

On another note: don't expose fields directly, encapsulate them in properties. Doing that, you can control the data getting into the class, also code outside the class itself can't influence the class in non-wanted ways.

Comment: Thanks, I know that it is not a good practise to use fields, I used fields only to test the binding, but then I realised that WPF can't use fields.